# Close CMD after starting a program

Tags: cmd

I use my own URI-Scheme for opening youtube videos in external video-player from browsers (potplayer://https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=*******):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\potplayer]
@="\"URL:potplayer protocol\""
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\potplayer\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\potplayer\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\potplayer\shell\open\command]
@="cmd /c (set \"var=%1\" & call set var=%%var:potplayer://=%% && call C:\\PotPlayer\\PotPlayer.exe %%var%%)"
```

It starts cmd for removing "potplayer://" from "potplayer://https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=*******"

And cmd is being closed only if video-player (PotPlayer.exe) is being closed. But cmd should be closed right after video-player starts.

Comment: start /b can be used to execute an application this way. Unfortunately I am not sure, if you can replace cmd with start in your case. Also see: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/start.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: "replace cmd" What do you mean? It can't be replaced. CMD must starts anyway. Start /b can be used in batch file to start program without opening cmd window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved this:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\potplayer\shell\open\command]
@="cmd /c (set var=%1 & call set var=%%var:potplayer://=%% && call start C:\\PotPlayer\\PotPlayer.exe %%var%%)
```